# Substring problems in suffix trees

Tags: data-structures, optimization, strings, suffix-trees

Assume that we have some efficient way of creating a **suffix tree** of a string. Then I'm interested in efficient ways of finding:

> **Length of longest repeated substring.** Given some string $S$, then a repeated substring is a substring $R$ of $S$ that occurs more than once in $S$. Then I wish to find the length of the longest repeated substring.

*Example.* Consider the string `yabbadabbado`, then the substring `abbad` occurs twice and is the longest repeated substring, so the answer would be $5$.

I'm also interested in the similar problem by shared substring of two strings.

> **Length of longest common substring.** Given strings $S_1$ and $S_2$ then a substring is a common substring if it is a substring of both $S_1$ and $S_2$. I wish to find the length of the longest common substring.

*Example.* Given strings `oompaloompa` and `boom` have longest common substring of `oom` and hence the answer would be $3$.

How can these be found efficiently?

Comment: See [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51065/finding-the-longest-repeating-subsequence) and [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/53826/which-is-the-proper-algorithm-to-figure-repeated-substrings-of-longest-total-len/53866#53866). I am confused by this question; if you already have suffix trees, the answer follows from their definition.

Comment: @Raphael I looked at the tag `suffix-trees` and didn't find those questions. It's actually not quite that I already have them as suffix trees, but I have some efficient blackbox algorithm for creating the suffix trees.

I am just trying to learn about suffix trees on my own, so I'm totally new to them, so that's why this question might seem quite silly. How exactly do the answers follow from their definition?

Comment: See [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/55575/how-to-find-longest-recurring-pattern-from-lage-string-data-set); I think answers the question quite comprehensively. (I'm saying it follows from the definition because it's quite clear that a suffix tree has exactly one node per distinct substring.)

Comment: (These questions don't have the [tag:suffix-trees] tag because they are not *about* suffix trees. It's often useful to use [Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Acs.stackexchange.com%20longest%20common%20substring%20suffix%20trees) for finding stuff on SE.)

Comment: @Raphael Yes, those questions were not about suffix trees. I'm just saying I did actually try to look for previous questions on these problems, but I stupidly looked the wrong place :-). So I thank you for the list of similar questions. It's getting a little late, so I hope I can solve these problems tomorrow with the help of those answers.

Comment: No worries, it can be hard to find things. I only remembered these because I answered some of them. ;) Thanks for looking in the first place!